# Return to KDE after starting new terminal

Tags: arch-linux, kde-4, linux-terminal

I've just installed Arch Linux with KDE as a desktop environment. However after some initial steps I need to login as root so I hit `Ctrl-Alt-F2` and I was thrown into the terminal (black screen/white letters). How can I return back to my KDE desktop without rebooting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You switched to a different "virtual console" – there are several separate 'workspaces' which you can switch between using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*num*</kbd> (or, inside Xorg, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*num*</kbd>), where *num* is the number of the virtual console. By default, text logins are available on the first six.

Depending on the method you started KDE, Xorg should be running on either VC #1 or #7.

Comment: yep, I'm in kubuntu; #7 worked for me